# PHP Scan directory for images - carousel

Tags: php, fancybox, carousel, scandir

I have a carousel on my website. Each slide looks like this:

```
<div class="item active">
    <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="img/gallery/country/large/01.jpg">
        <img src="img/gallery/country/thumb/01.jpg" alt="Default Image 1" />
    </a>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="img/gallery/country/large/01.jpg">
        <img src="img/gallery/country/thumb/01.jpg" alt="Image 2" />
    </a>
</div>  
<div class="item">
    <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="img/gallery/country/large/01.jpg">
        <img src="img/gallery/country/thumb/01.jpg" alt="Image 3" />
    </a>
</div>
```

I am wanting to use php to scan a 'large' and 'thumb' folder of the images and to build the slider into the above format. If there are no images, there will be no output so no slider will display.

I have 2 folders here which I do not know if this will seriously complicate things. Alternatively, I can have any folder structure but ideally I would like a thumb file and a large image file.

So, does anyone have any suggestions for me? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
// this assumes that ABC.JPG exists in both "img/gallery/country/thumb/" and "img/gallery/country/large/"!
$thumbs = glob("img/gallery/country/thumb/*.jpg");

if(count($thumbs)) {
  natcasesort($thumbs);
  foreach($thumbs as $thumb) {
    ?>
    <div class="item">
        <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="img/gallery/country/large/<?php echo basename($thumb) ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $thumb ?>" alt="" />
        </a>
    </div>  
    <?php
  }
} else {
  echo "No images";
}
```

Comment: Syntax error: <?php // this assumes that ABC.JPG exists in both "img/gallery/country/thumb/" and "img/gallery/country/large/"!
       $thumbs = glob("/img/gallery/africa/thumb/*.jpg"); ?>
       <?php
       if(count($thumbs)) {
         natcasesort($thumbs);
         foreach($thumbs as $thumb) {
         ?>
          <li class="item">
              <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="/img/gallery/africa/large/<?php echo basename($thumb) ?>">                  <img src="<?php echo $thumb ?>" alt="" />              </a>          </li> 
           
<?php
} else {
echo "No images!";
}
?>

Comment: `<?php $thumbs = glob("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT/img/gallery/africa/thumb/*.jpg"); ?>` is your problem. Look at the `$_SERVER` part. 

This should look like 
`glob("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/img/gallery/africa/thumb/*.jpg")` 

-- relative paths work as well...

Comment: Sorry, that was my typo! That wasn't the problem unfortunately..
http://pastebin.com/B6yUjDTS

Comment: Sorry, I was missing a `}` for my `foreach` loop. Answer updated.

Comment: Sorry, yeah I just added it a few mins ago! Thanks for updating.. This works now apart from sourcing the images! If I leave it at "/img/gallery/country/large/*.jpg" it echos no images. If I use my usual php document root, the same!

Comment: Get rid of the prefixed `/` - just use `img/gallery/country/large/*.jpg` -- ASSUMING your `img` folder resides in the same directory as your PHP file.

Comment: GOT IT! Okay.. I'll post my code as an edit to yours! Thanks a lot mate.. really appreciate it

Comment: Ha, looks what's just popped up on my hosting server!
Warning: natcasesort() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /assets/country-gallery-js.php on line 14

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /assets/country-gallery-js.php on line 15

Personally, I've read up and read through tutorials and I don't know why it isn't simply running the echo. The code should run the echo if there are no images in the folder.

**[Posted the code HERE](http://pastebin.com/qB3cFJas)**

Comment: Did you `var_dump($thumbs)`?  Make sure it's an array. You could also do `if(is_array($thumbs) && count($thumbs))`

Comment: I have changed the solution now to an array.. that seems to do the job now just fine. Same concept though. Thanks Rob :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [glob](http://php.net/glob) to find your files:

```
<?php
foreach (glob("img/gallery/country/large/*.jpg") as $image) {
  echo $image;
}
```